# Twice differentiable positive complex function has positive derivative on upper half disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb C : \Im(z) \geq 0, |z|\leq1\}$ be the upper half of the unit disc, $u : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb C  $ a twice continuously differentiable function such that $u(x) = 0$ for real $x \in [-1,1]$ and $u \geq 0$.

---

I want to show: If $u_y = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =0 $ on $(-1,1)$, then $u = 0$ throughout $\Omega$.

---

Unfortunately, I haven't made any progress yet - do you have any ideas?

Comment: So you really want $\Omega$ compact?

Comment: Yeah, it says in the question that $\Omega$ is compact. But I just found out that $u$ doesn't necessarily have to be harmonic.... now this possibly makes more sense. I have changed this in my question now -- Sorry.

Comment: That's false as now stated. Just look at $u(x,y) = y^2.$

Comment: Oh my god -- this claim seemed suspicious and implausible to me all the time, but as I was thinking of a counterexample myself, I didn't come up with something as simple! Great, thank you. Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees^^

Comment: There is a nice result here about harmonic functions.